# In Shiny, is it possible to make variables in session shareable to some users, but not all of them?

Tags: r, shiny

I know that in Shiny (R) it is possible to make variable shareable to all users or just to one user, e.g. that's an example where value in `data` variable will be accessible for all users:

```
library(shiny)

data <- reactiveVal() # defined outside of server

ui <- fluidPage(
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And below is an example where value from variable `data` will be created for each session (each user) individually:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
data <- reactiveVal() # defined inside the server
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And thus - the value is not shareable to other users (sessions).

My question is - are the indirect stages possible, i.e. share the variable for some users, but not all of them? I have never heard about this, so I'm afraid this is not possible by default, but if I would like to do this, how to start? What should I know?

I can imagine this could be possible by writing / reading something to disk and then manage access depending on group which user belong, but I'm asking about the solution similar to this described above.

Comment: Not really. You can try to do in-app user-authorization based on `session$user`, but I know of nothing that provides that already.

Comment: @r2evans if you are familiar with this, can you also give me some key-words or links related to this topic? I mean - concept of shareable environment in case of Shiny (JavaScript?)?

Comment: No. The only thing I'm familiar with is the availability of `session$user`. I've never used it for *authorization*, though it is not hard to brute-force it: `sensitive_data <- reactive({ if (!session$user %in% list_of_allowed_people) return(NULL); ... })` is one start. The biggest question in my mind is how to maintain this list of allowed people in a robust, flexible, and secure manner.

Answer (score 1):

The shiny environment has a dedicated item (and `environment`) to store specific user data, which can be accessed through `session$userData`. This object can be used to store, for example, user ID. When that is available, it become a simple matter of allowing/disallowing access based on user rights.

Comment: Thanks. If you can, have time, can you provide some simple MRE on how it could work? I didn't consider session$userData before and never used it, but I just started to read about this. But now I'm a little sceptic taking into account @r2evans comment to my question.

Comment: There's two separate challenges to tackle here: first, how to identify/authenticate a user (which is what @r2evans comment is about). second, how to allow access, which is simply a matter of setting `session$userData$userIsAllowedAccess = T` and then providing access based on the value. I'm not a cyber security expert, so I can't comment on how safe any of that is.